# VS 2015 : System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to clean a Solution (Windows or Web) in visual studio. it is crashed with this error messages:

> System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll

Thanks for your help,

Regards.

Comment: In my case I've got this error because I had a mismatch with a package used by a custom library. In your case you can try to restore your package and check if their versions match together.